# Suggestions for inexpensive embedded linux hardware with screen

Tags: embedded-systems

I'm looking for embedded linux hardware that supports USB and preferably serial though that can be accomplished with USB.  It also need to have a screen with either buttons on the side or a touch screen.  A tablet that runs linux (not android) is acceptable so long as a USB hub can be attached and it can act as a USB host and charge at the same time.  I need to run applications that are written as standard linux apps.

Right now I'm prototyping but I anticipate needing 10-100/year so a one off surplus device won't work.

The obvious answer is a raspberry pi and the newly released screen, but I'm wondering if people know of other options out there that are cheaper or smaller (the 7" screen is okay but bigger than I need).

Answer (score 4):

PocketChip (http://getchip.com/pages/pocketchip) may satisfy your needs, but may be overkill. It has a very small QWERTY keyboard, a 4.3" screen and a battery, for $50. It is not clear whether the USB output is exposed or not, only the GPIO is mentioned...

The other gotcha is that it **has not been released yet**, and there is no specific launch date for it yet (the board itself will start to ship in May 2016).

Comment: It should be noted that this product hasn't been released yet. C.H.I.P. is estimated to ship sometime in June 2016, while the keyboard/screen does not say when the expected ship date will be.